# Extract system of linear equations from the linearly independent vectors

Tags: equation-solving, pattern-matching, coefficients

Dear StackExchange Community,

I have a lot of linearly independent vectors, e[i]e[j], e[i]e[j]h[i], f[i]e[j], etc, and I have an equation for example

```
a1 e[i]e[j] + 3a2 e[i]e[j] + a2 e[i]e[j]h[i] - a2 f[i]e[j] + a3 f[i]e[j] = 0.
```

I want to find a function which takes the equation (and nothing else), and returns the following system of linear equations:

```
a1 + 3a2 = 0, a2 = 0, - a2 + a3 = 0.
```

I know how to make that function (using patterns) if I specify vectors which appear in the equation. The problem is that my equation in reality is made of more than 100 vectors, so I am trying to avoid listing them.

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using [`CoefficientRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientRules.html):

```
expr = 
 a1 e[i] e[j] + 3 a2 e[i] e[j] + a2 e[i] e[j] h[i] - a2 f[i] e[j] + a3 f[i] e[j]
(* a1 e[i] e[j] + 3 a2 e[i] e[j] - a2 e[j] f[i] + a3 e[j] f[i] + a2 e[i] e[j] h[i] *)

components = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, _e | _f | _h, All]
(* {e[i], e[j], f[i], h[i]} *)

coefficients = CoefficientRules[expr, components]
(* {{1, 1, 0, 1} -> a2, {1, 1, 0, 0} -> 
  a1 + 3 a2, {0, 1, 1, 0} -> -a2 + a3} *)

#2 == 0 & @@@ coefficients
(* {a2 == 0, a1 + 3 a2 == 0, -a2 + a3 == 0} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Can this be modified if I have noncommutative multiplication, for example e[i]**e[j], e[i]**e[j]**h[i], f[i]**e[j]? It seems to me that above doesn't work in this case.